# Capistrano use a custom name for release_path folder

Tags: deployment, capistrano, capistrano3

Capistrano uses "%Y%m%d%H%M%S" to name the release_path folder.
So that the folder hierarchy looks like;

path/to/deploy

```
      |------ shared
      |------repo
      |------current
      |------releases
                |-------20180119074130
                |-------20180119075214
                |-------20180119085130
```

Would there be a possibility to use my own defined variable so that the releases inside releases folder looks like below;

path/to/deploy

```
      |------ shared
      |------repo
      |------current
      |------releases
                |-------20180119-001
                |-------20180119-002
                |-------20180119-003
```

Comment: You might be able to override the `#set_release_path` method: https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/blob/9eb0b06f2c5bb2d4ee9699ddf8b5d0c073f9d76e/lib/capistrano/dsl/paths.rb#L25

Comment: would that applied to all environments? I only need to make this to one environment. such as only for Production and not for QA and UAT?

Comment: You _might_ be able to do the override inside of the deployment stage file (`config/deploy/production.rb`). Otherwise, I'd try to wrap the `def` in an `if` statement. It depends on when things are evaluated.